# Every Cauchy Sequence in the real number line converges

Tags: general-topology

Prove that every cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges

proof: Let ($a_n$) where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Let's first prove that it is bounded. Choose $\epsilon = 1$, then for some $N$, $\forall n,m > N$ $$|a_m - a_n| < 1$$ Set m = N + 1 $$|a_{N + 1} - a_n| < 1$$ Now, by the Triangle Inequality $$|a_N|| = |a_n - a_{N+1} + a_{N+1}|$$ $$|a_N| \leq |a_{N+1}| + 1, \forall n\geq N$$ By Bolzano-Weierstrass ($a_n$) has a convergent sequence $a_{n_{k}}\rightarrow a$, lets say. So, let $\epsilon > 0$ Then, $$\exists N_1 \ \text{such that} \ w\geq N_1 \Rightarrow |a_{n_{w}} - L| < \epsilon/2$$ Also, $$\exists N_2 \ \text{such that} \ m,n\geq N_2 \Rightarrow |a_m - a_n| < \epsilon/2$$ Let $N = \min(N_1,N_2)$. Then $$m,n\geq N \Rightarrow |a_m - a_n| \leq $$

So, I want to use the triangle inequality here but I having some trouble after this point, maybe I didn't define something right before continuing and that's what is preventing me to finish, any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to tell you that you better let $N$ be the $\max$ instad of the $\min$ of $N_1,N_2$. But actually, we can get along with $N=N_2$. Also note that you don't want to show anything about $|a_m-a_n|$. Instead you want to show that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ (to conclude $a_n\to L$; and incidentally you use both $a$ and $L$, both intended to mean the same): Given $n\ge N$, we can find $w$ such that $w\ge N_1$ and also $n_w\ge N$ (the latter because $n_w\to \infty$). Then 
$$|a_n-L|=|a_n-a_w+a_w-L|\le |a_n-a_w|+|a_w-L|<\frac\epsilon2+\frac\epsilon2=\epsilon $$

Comment: But you don't know about $|a_w-L|,$ otherwise the proof is already completed. Maybe you meant to write $a_{n_w}$ instead of $a_w?$

Answer (score 2):

Define $N\ge max(N_1, N_2)$ as an integer such that $n_w\ge N_2, \forall w\ge N.$ Then $$\mid a_m-L\mid\le\mid a_m-a_{n_m}\mid+\mid a_{n_m}-L\mid\lt\epsilon, \forall m \ge N.$$

Hope this helps.